# Converting underscore templates to Handlebar templates

Tags: backbone.js, handlebars.js, underscore.js-templating

I have this code in underscore.js template
   Can anybody help me with how it can be written using handlebar.js templates instead of underscore?

```
 <% _.each(cruds, function (crud) { %>
```

which gets a crud list and displays it as follows

```
           <tr>
                <td><%= crud.id %></td>
                <td><%= crud.name %></td>
                <td><%= crud.email %></td>
                <td><%= crud.phone %></td>
                <td><%= crud.address %></td>
           </tr>
            <% }); %>
```

Same for this line of code as well

```
    <% if (_.isEmpty(cruds)){ %>
```

Any Help would be appreciated